# AngularJs load the needed Scripts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, include

*Hi, I couln't find an exact answer to my problem on the internet*

I'm currently playing around with AngularJs and I've realised, that I have to load every single file in my `index.html`.

It doesn't feel very smooth doing it like this and I'm pretty sure that it affects the loading time.

Is there any way to do this in a proper and faster way?

---

**index.html:**

```html
<!-- modules -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<!-- controllers -->
<script src="js/controllers/Controller00.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/Controller01.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/Controller02.js"></script>
<!-- directives -->
<script src="js/directives/Directive00.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives/Directive01.js"></script>
<!-- services -->
<script src="js/services/Service00.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/Service01.js"></script>
```

**app.js**

```js
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute']).config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      redirectTo: '/00'
    })
    .when('/00', {
      templateUrl: 'view/00.html',
      controller: 'Controller00',
      controllerAs: 'ctrl00'
    })
    .when('/01', {
      templateUrl: 'view/01.html'
    })
    .when('/02', {
      templateUrl: 'view/02.html',
      controller: 'Controller02',
      controllerAs: 'ctrl02'
    })
    .when('/03', {
      templateUrl: 'view/03.html',
      controller: 'Controller03',
      controllerAs: 'ctrl03'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/00'
    });
});
```

Comment: if you want to use the page very smooth means you have to use router technics

Comment: @Vinoth I am using routing. I've added my app.js. Have a look

Answer (score 1):

You can lazy load your modules and components using third party like 
ocLazyLoad

Check their docs
https://oclazyload.readme.io/

Comment: I'll have a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a task runner (like grunt, gulp etc ..) to concat, minifiy, uglify your code and load a single *.min.js file.

Or, you can use a static module bundler as well. Webpack, for example, is well documented, - specially for Angular - and you can use it to packet AngularJS application also.

For what concerns ocLazyLoad (suggested by another user) be aware that AngularJS isn't designed to support lazy loading. **OcLazyLoad**, that I've used, **overrides** some AngulrJS core method, like the **angular.boostrap** function (just to provide an example) and so, with it, you are not running AngularJS anymore, but a "fork" ...

Then, IMHO, serve files enabling gzip (server side).

Comment: Not really the solution I'm looking for, although it will lower the load-time, I don't want to do something like that, especially not in early development of my application.

Answer (score 0):

Go for Bundling and Minification which provide a way to  reduce the number of requests needed to get JS and CSS resource files and reduce the size of the files.

> It doesn't feel very smooth doing it like this and I'm pretty sure
>   that it affects the loading time.

It helps when you are debugging and developing, when you want to publish the code all your JS files should be bundled into a single file. Don't worry about the performance as the static content gets cached in the browser.

As a best practice use a package manager, it will help you to organize your files. You can check [Bower](https://bower.io/)

If you really want to implement best web development practices, I suggest you visit [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/)

Yeoman helps you to kickstart new projects, prescribing best practices and tools to help you stay productive.

Comment: Hi, I'm not really worried about the loading time (yet). It just bugs me that I have to copy-paste the include for every-single-file on the index.html. It just doesn't feel like *clean* coding.

Comment: Use a packacge manager like Bower. It will help and simplify your development.